# Loan Calculating late payment with daily 0.2% on arrears

Tags: php, finance, calculation

I am trying to calculate a late daily fee of 0.02%, but when the second installment is reached the late fee adds the second installment plus total fee from first installment and now calculate daily fee with new accrued figure.

**Example**

First installment 5 days late before reaching second instalment:

```
fee=(arrears*5*0.002)
```

Second instalment is reached and loan overdue for another 5 days:

```
fee2=((instalment2+fee)*5*0.002))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Fabricio my question is how do I solve the above using php

Comment: I have a loan of 10,000 with 10% interest so total loan of 11000 payable on equal instalment for 11 months. each month I pay 1000, on the 1st month Incase I fail to pay on mature day there’s a daily fee of 0.02% of the unpaid instalment in this case if the loan is not paid for 1st month so penalty = (1000 * 0.02% * no_of_late_days). Assume the loan has gone unpaid on second month where am supposed now to pay another 1000. The system should add (1000+Penalt of 1st month)* 0.02% * no_of_days_late_for_ second_month) and the trend goes on to all months up to the 11th month.

Comment: Just change the array of the answer to 11 months. Create 0 to 10 $ArrayInstalments[], configuring value 1000 and the day of each one payment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the interest use Compound Interest the formula (arrears*(1+0.002)^5), not Simple Interest formula (arrears*5*0.002).

Anyway, I made a piece of code to show how can you do it.

```
<?php
    function CalculateLoan($Value,$Days,$Fee){
        //Simple Interest
        return $Value + $Value*$Days*$Fee;
        //Compound interest
        //return $Value * pow(1+$Fee,$Days);
    }

    // Assuming 6 Instalments of $1000 every 5 days.
    $ArrayInstalments = array();
    $ArrayInstalments[0]= array("Value"=>1000,"PayDay"=>0);
    $ArrayInstalments[1]= array("Value"=>1000,"PayDay"=>5);
    $ArrayInstalments[2]= array("Value"=>1000,"PayDay"=>10);
    $ArrayInstalments[3]= array("Value"=>1000,"PayDay"=>15);
    $ArrayInstalments[4]= array("Value"=>1000,"PayDay"=>20);
    $ArrayInstalments[5]= array("Value"=>1000,"PayDay"=>25);


    // 30 days passed
    $CurrentDay = 30;

    // 0.2% fee/day
    $Fee = 0.002;

    // Initial Debit
    $Sum = 0;

    foreach ($ArrayInstalments as $key=>$Instalment){
        $ThisDebit = CalculateLoan($Instalment['Value'],max($CurrentDay-$Instalment['PayDay'],0),$Fee);
        echo 'Instalment:'.$key.' Debit:' . $ThisDebit . '<br/>';
        $Sum += $ThisDebit;
    }
    echo 'Total:' .$Sum.  '<br/>';
?>
```